# Why does ReadManyItemsAsync perform query operation when MS docs says it doesn't in Cosmos?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

According to MS documents, ReadManyItemsAsync should be doing the cheapest lookup type possible with an RU charge of 1 for each item. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-dotnet-read-item
Why do I keep seeing a charge for Query not just in my direct call but also in my traces. Since query is at a minimum 2.5 X the cost of read this is not making sense. I should note I am sending a single id/partitionKey in my test. It should come back with a charge of 1.xx.
I have implemented the code exactly as the example have stated, using both the ID and PartitionKeys .

```
            if (ids.Count != partitionKeys.Count)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("ids and partitionKey counts must match"); 
            
            var container = Database.GetContainer(containerId); 
            List<(string, PartitionKey)> itemsToFind = new(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count(); i++)
            {
                itemsToFind.Add((ids[i],new PartitionKey(partitionKeys[i])));
            }

            var result  = await container.ReadManyItemsAsync<T>(items: itemsToFind);
            return result; 

        }
```

But when I look at that call, I see it is using Query and it is charging me 2.95RU. I am fully aware it also charges by payload. That is not the issue here. The issue is the docs say it doesn't do query.. but I see query.
[image]
So I would ask...what is going on here?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to the API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.readmanyitemsasync?view=azure-dotnet#remarks

> is meant to perform better latency-wise than a query with IN statements to fetch a large number of independent items.

The main scenario is to provide a better latency-wise alternative to a `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id IN () and c.partitionKey = xx`, which is what most people would do if they knew the Ids and Partition Key values of a group of items they wanted to read.

That would explain why you are seeing the Query operations, because the implementation internally are optimized queries (vs the IN query).

I agree that the documentation you linked (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-dotnet-read-item#read-multiple-items-asynchronously) is a bit misleading because it says it will do point operations, we'll take your feedback and improve the wording and explanation to be better.

Comment: Hi Matias. The documentation is extremely misleading as it states it is doing point reads. 
`Container.ReadManyItemsAsync<> returns a list of items based on the unique identifiers and partition keys you provide. This operation is typically more performant than a query since you'll effectively perform a point read operation on all items in the list.`
I guess there is nothing to fix in the ticket since it is by design.

Comment: Agree, and we have already worked on updating the documentation to reflect better what the implementation does.
At this moment, there is no point-read usage on ReadMany.